# Outlook for Mac High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, ms-office

I have been looking for few days and cannot find anything.

Where can I download Outlook for Mac as suitable for High Sierra?

Comment: The last standalone version of Office that worked on High Sierra is [Office 2016 for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2019-office-2016-or-office-2013-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479#OfficeVersion=Office_2016_for_Mac). I think you can still get it, but you need a current MS365 subscription.

Comment: The last version of Office for Mac that runs on High Sierra is 16.43. You can get it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-for-mac. To run it, you need registration.

Comment: Those are *updater* packages @lhf, not full installers.  Also, the release notes for v16.x makes no mention of Office for Mac 2016

Comment: @Allan, the Office suite links are full installers.

Comment: I clicked on them, they all had updater as part of the filename.

Comment: Can you explain your use case a bit more? What have you been using on High Sierra instead of Outlook for the last six years? Is this a 2011 vintage Mac, that can't be upgraded?